# Not able to append arrays into a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I want to run this code to find a random element of a list containing numpy arrays with a certain condition

The conditions are that is for every element of arr1 not equal to arr2 it will append the element of that index of `er` and append it to `lst`:

```
import numpy as np
import random
arr1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
arr2 = np.array([1,2,6,3])
arr = (arr1 == arr2)
er = np.array([[1,2],[-6,7],[4,7],[6,2]])

lst = []
for i in arr:
    if i == False:
        lst.append(er[i])

print(random.choice(lst))
```

But I don't know why its returning a empty list.Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

arr is a boolean array, so in for loop i is True/False values (not an index)

```
for i in arr:
```

Change

```
for i in arr:
    if i == False:
        lst.append(er[i])
```

To:

```
for i, v in enumerate(arr):   # retrieving index and value
    if v == False:            # test value
        lst.append(er[i])     # use i to index into er
```

Comment: Perfecty explained

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import numpy as np
import random
arr1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
arr2 = np.array([1,2,6,3])
arr = (arr1 == arr2)
er = np.array([[1,2],[-6,7],[4,7],[6,2]])

lst = []
for i in range(len(arr1-1)):
    if arr1[i] != arr2[i]:
        lst.append(er[i])

print(random.choice(lst))
```